# Google Maps API V2, I want to restrict the map to a bounding box

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I want to limit the visible map to a pre-defined rectangle on screen. For example, I am making a mapping application of a famous location with polylines and polygons on top of the map, and I do not want my users to scroll outside of the map. Is there a simple way to achieve this?

I have looked through documentation and want to be able to set the [VisibleRegion](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/VisibleRegion.html) on the map, but there appears no clean-cut solution.

So here is my first attempt. It is ok in that if the user goes outside the map, it brings them back. However, I want it to stop immediately and prevent further interaction.

```
public class RestrictedMapView extends MapView implements GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener {

private CameraPosition mCameraPosition;

private LatLngBounds mRegion;

private int mMaxZoom, mMinZoom;

private boolean mTouchEnabled = true;

private GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener mCameraChangeListener;

private GoogleMap.CancelableCallback mCancelCallback = new GoogleMap.CancelableCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        mTouchEnabled = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {

    }
};

public RestrictedMapView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public RestrictedMapView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public RestrictedMapView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public RestrictedMapView(Context context, GoogleMapOptions options) {
    super(context, options);
}

/**
 * Call this after map has been created
 */
public void initialize(){
    getMap().setOnCameraChangeListener(this);
}

public void setOnCameraChangeListener(GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener onCameraChangeListener){
    this.mCameraChangeListener = onCameraChangeListener;
}

/**
 * Sets the visible region we restrict the map to being in
 * @param visibleRegion
 */
public void setVisibleRegion(int minZoom, int maxZoom, LatLngBounds visibleRegion){
    mRegion = visibleRegion;
    mMinZoom = minZoom;
    mMaxZoom = maxZoom;
}

@Override
public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
    if(mCameraChangeListener!=null){
        mCameraChangeListener.onCameraChange(cameraPosition);
    }

    if(!mRegion.contains(cameraPosition.target)){
        mTouchEnabled = false;
        getMap().animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(mRegion, 0), mCancelCallback);
    } else {
        mCameraPosition = cameraPosition;
        if(mCameraPosition.zoom>mMaxZoom){
            mTouchEnabled = false;
            CameraPosition cameraPosition1 = new CameraPosition(cameraPosition.target, mMaxZoom, cameraPosition.tilt, cameraPosition.bearing);
            getMap().animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition1), mCancelCallback);

        } else if(mCameraPosition.zoom<mMinZoom){
            mTouchEnabled = false;
            CameraPosition cameraPosition1 = new CameraPosition(cameraPosition.target, mMinZoom, cameraPosition.tilt, cameraPosition.bearing);
            getMap().animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition1), mCancelCallback);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if(mTouchEnabled) {
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    } else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Can you not just stop user interaction with the map?

Comment: The user needs to be able to pinch and zoom and scroll around the map. Do you mean as in based on the camera position we prevent user from scrolling any further?

Comment: I am unaware of a method that limits the user to a specific area. Maybe you will have to handle this the application end and stop user interaction when a bounds has been reached